# Gnuplot - How to plot heatmap with quadratic fields

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I'm quite unexperienced with gnuplot. I was working with the demos on this site: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html

I managed to get a heatmap with:

```
set title "Heat Map"
unset key
set tic scale 0

set palette rgbformula 30,31,32
set cbrange [0:40]
set cblabel "Compactness"
unset cbtics

set xrange [-0.5:105.5]
set yrange [-0.5:27.5]

set view map
set terminal gif
set output "heatmap.gif"
splot '-' matrix with image
```

But as in the example this produces rectangles. How can I make gnuplot plot quadratic fields/pixels/points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `splot` for a heatmap. Just use `plot ... with image`. For a 2D plot you can use `set size ratio -1` to have the same units on both axes.

Consider the test data file `test.dat`:

```
1 2 3 4 3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 3 9 8 2 9 4
```

With the minimal script

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'

set autoscale fix
set size ratio -1
set palette rgbformulae 30,31,32
plot 'test.dat' matrix with image
```

you get the result (with 4.6.3):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The image is quite small now. Do you have a hint how to properly upscale the image?

Comment: You must set an appropriate terminal (i.e. image) size, like `set terminal pngcairo size 1500,500`.

Comment: Works well, thank you. :) (I lost one setting at first.)